# Pass a jwPlayer variable to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jwplayer

Working with jwplayer (latest and licensed version) I can't seem to pass the value of getDuration() to a jQuery variable. The data is undefined when the function below closes.

```
jwplayer('jwvideo').onPlay(function() { 
    videoLength = jwplayer().getDuration();
});
```

I already tried every possible variation with:

```
var test = videoLength;
```

The only thing I need is to pass 'videoLength' in to a dataString like:

```
var dataString = 'address='+ address + '&mediaNr=' + mediaNr;
```

I went through all the questions about this on this site.

Hence I seriously need help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you won't get anything in `videoLength` until jwPlayer `onPlay` event is fired.

Then you need to manage the variable scope properly. Consider reading ups something like this answer- [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

I'd do something like:

```
<script>
var videoLength

jwplayer('jwvideo').onPlay(function() { 
    videoLength = jwplayer().getDuration();
});

console.log( videoLength )

</script>
```

should give you duration ( given jwplayer().getDuration() is correct method for this ).